# Does a thread notity another joined thread when it finishes execution?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, try-catch

I'm developing an Android app.

I have two threads. The first one has to wait the second one.

I have this code on the **first thread** `run` method:

```
@Override
public void run() {

  synchronized (this.secondThread) {
      this.secondThread.wait();
  }

   [...]
}
```

And on my **second thread**:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    synchronized (MyClass.myLock) {

        try {

            // Do something important here

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // manage exception
            return;
        }
        finally {
            // do something...
        }
    }

    synchronized (this) {
        this.notify();
    }

    [...]
```

}

As you can see, **there is a return inside catch block.**

With this code, **will first thread get notified if an exception occurs on the second thread?**

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: It's a code that I have found somewhere and I don't know if the first will be notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will first thread get notified if an exception occurs on the second
>   thread?

Answer is no. Unless you **explicitly** `notify()` in catch block before returning, the other thread will **not wake up**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, what about `synchronized (MyClass.myLock) {`?  When an exception occurs, it will go out the synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. In order to get both notify the has to be `synchronized` on the same object. `this` can be different. If you want all the thread waiting on a object to be notify you havo to call `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()`. The `notifyAll(`)  should be put inside the `finally` block. Infact despite the return the finally block is alway executed

Answer (score 0):

The `notify()` should be inside the finally block if you want it to work unconditionally, but you should really be using `Thread.join()` instead of `wait()`: then the thread being waited on doesn't have to do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. Unless you explicitly notify() in catch block before returning, the other thread will not wake up, You have to Al possible exceptions and in every case notify to your first thread, make sure that your first thread input is not dependent on second thread output otherwise you may phase some other problem in thread 1.